# Measure consumed in and out bandwidth from s3 bucket in Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, io

I am using cloud computing with Amazon S3 bucket. Recently the cost for outbounds usage from S3 exploded. I made various changes to my code, hence I am not able to pinpoint the source of the extra cost. Is there a python package that could help me measure my io with S3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [Log requests using server access logging - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html).

Server Access Logging will create (many) log files in Amazon S3 where you can monitor requests and the size (`Bytes Sent`) of responses.

See: [Amazon S3 server access log format - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/LogFormat.html)

The number of log files, and the amount of content within each log file, can make it difficult to analyze.  You might want to **use Amazon Athena to query these access logs**.

See: [Analyze S3 server access logs using Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena/)